# How to use mongoose-double package

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDB and mongoose library installed. Now if I want to use the mongoose-double package, does it require to be installed separately before? I want to store latitude and longitude data in double.

Below is my package.json file.

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.11",
    "monk": "^7.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the `mongoose-double` package before using that. You can install it using:

```
npm i mongoose-double
```

And then initialize your mongoose object like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I included this package in my package.json file. And also did I initialized as said. But my lat-lng coordinates are still saved in string format. How shall I parse them to double before storing in mongo? I checked many places but can't get it working

Comment: ```var newUser = {
            'username': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
            'location': {type: "Point", coordinates: [
                $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocationLng').val(),
                $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocationLat').val()] },
            'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
            'phone': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserPhone').val(),
            'chat': $('#addUser fieldset select#inputChatAllowed').val()                     
        }```

Comment: Creating object from form fetched values and later passing through ajax call. And then inserting into a collection. Can you assist me here?

Comment: I referred this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-double